# How can I get sub-sums of a column based on another columns unique values?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with the following setup

```
A       B      C
ItemID, Type,  Count
0001,   Apple, 8
0002,   Peach, 3
0003,   Apple, 8
0004,   Pear,  2
0005,   Apple, 4
```

And I would like to produce the following sheet

```
D      E
Type,  Total
Apple, 20
Peach, 3
Pear,  2
```

I can generate the unique `Type` with `UNIQUE` and generate the first column of the desired output, but I can't quite figure how to get the second.

I have tried `SUMIF(C1:C6, B1:B6==D1:D6)` but it seems the `==` does not do an element-wise matching.

---

**How can I get sub-sums of a column based on another columns unique values?**

Answer (score 0):

Use `query()`, like this:

`=query(A1:C, "select B, sum(C) where B is not null group by B", 1)`